# WatiN Test Project Best Practices

Tags: testing, project-management, watin

After building up and running lots of WatiN tests, what are some good ways to organize the tests? If I was asked "Do we have a test that does X, then Y?" How would I look that up? Would it be with all tests surrounding X or Y?

It seems after getting lots of tests in here, organization becomes a bit of an issue. I'm just looking for some advice to help us keep our tests well named and organized, thus, more maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about drawing some sort of equivalence between Nunit Categories and features then you could use categories as "tags" for what features are addressed.

Comment: The best solution I can think of is using the categories like you mentioned, but categorizing them with constants as the tags. This way I can find usages with ReSharper to see where all the usages of tag SHOPPING_CART are. For multiple tags on a test method, you could use [Test, Category(SHOPPING_CART + PAYMENT_PAGE)]. Still not my ideal solution, but better than nothing.